# How to access Atlassian using PHP

Tags: php, curl, confluence

I want to fetch content from my Atlassian with username and password.

The URL typically looks like:

**http://my-own-site.atlassian.net/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?spaceKey=TO&title=Any-Wiki-Title**

Is it possible to use *PHP CURL* to fetch content from this page?

So far I am only getting 401 auth reqd error.

**I have looked through Stackoverflow and all I am getting is how to access basic atlassian.com and bitbucket.org pages.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this code in php, you can create Confluence Pages:

```
<?php

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://localhost:8090/rest/api/content/");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{\"type\":\"page\",\"title\":\"**inserttitle**\",\"space\":{\"key\":\"**insertspace**\"},\"ancestors\":[{\"type\":\"page\",\"id\":**insertancestor**}],\"body\":{\"storage\":{\"value\":\"<p>This is a new page</p>\",\"representation\":\"storage\"}}}");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "**insertusername**" . ":" . "**insertpassword**");

    $headers = array();
    $headers[] = "Content-Type: application/json";
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if (curl_errno($ch)) {
        echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
    }
    curl_close ($ch);

    ?>
```

And with this code, you can get content from Confluence:

```
<?php

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://localhost:8090/rest/api/content/**insertid**");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "**insertusername**" . ":" . "**insertpassword**");
    $headers = array();
    $headers[] = "Content-Type: application/json";
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if (curl_errno($ch)) {
        echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
    }
    curl_close ($ch);   

?>



   echo $result;
```

Modify the parameter. I marked the words with insert*

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is certainly possible to access Atlassian products using PHP and cURL. I do it all the time to create/modify Jira issues

You will have to find/write a library (or set of libraries) which will allow you to access REST API calls. In my case, I wrote a base REST library which can then be inherited to create Jira, Confluence, *any other REST service* libraries

Search the Atlassian documentation site to find the REST API for the product you're using (Confluence in your case I would guess)

Don't forget that the REST API uses GET, POST, PUT and DELETE methods so your library will need to handle all of these

With regards to your error, I **think** your login will need to be allowed access to the API calls

Comment: thanks for your answer but I am not understanding why all those pages referring to localhost:port. What has it got to do with localhost ?

Comment: You would replace the `localhost:port` with the server name/ip address and port that your Atlassian installation is accessed via

Answer (score 1):

```
To retrieve any existing content properties for a piece of content, use url as https://your-domain.atlassian.net/wiki/rest/api/content/{content_ID}
$curl = curl_init();
$post = array(
    "id" => "{content_ID}",
    "type" => "{content_ID}", //Ex. page
    "title" => "{content_Title}",
    "space" => ["key" => "{spaces_key}"],
    "body" => ["storage" => ["value" => "<p>Here comes the other text</p>", "representation" => "storage"]],
        "version" => ["number" => 15]
    );
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://your-domain.atlassian.net/wiki/rest/api/content/{content_ID}?expand=metadata.properties.myprop,space,body.view,version,container",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 300,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($post),
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "authorization: Basic {base64 of (username:password)}",
        "content-type: application/json",
        'Accept: application/json'
    ),
));
$result = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```